# Google Fonts: multiple "Font" requests instead of one

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

I load Google Fonts this way:

```
<link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" rel="preconnect">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600,700,800|Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I analyze requests in a browser, there is **one CSS request** instead of two, so this is good that it loads two fonts with one request:
[https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600,700,800|Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&subset=latin-ext](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600,700,800%7CRoboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&subset=latin-ext)

However, when I switch to "Fonts" tab, I see 7 requests like these:
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459Wlhyw.woff2
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_bZF3gnD_g.woff2
(...)
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4.woff2
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51S7ACc6CsQ.woff2

In summary, there are 5 Montserrat requests and 2 for Roboto.
Could you explain me why? Maybe I don't understand something and these one are not typical requests at all. But if they are, is there a way to load it all with one request?

Comment: There's often a distinct font file for each font face/weight/style combination that you've selected. Roboto likely has the distinct weights in the font file, so you get 2, one for normal and one for italic. You should've only gotten 4 requests at most for Montserrat since you only requested 4 weights. As for reducing the number of connections, while there are protocols for doing that, it requires server cooperation. I suspect the browser hides the fact of multiple requests in a single connection. As in the Networking tab is oriented towards files rather than actual connections.